# printf("%s") returning weird values

Tags: c

I've got a function which does some stuff with strings, however it has to save the original string by copying it into a char array, making it all upper-case and substitute any w/W for V.

```
char* function(const char* text){

  int textLength = strlen(text);
  char text_copy[textLength];

  for(int i = 0; i < textLength; i++){
    if(text[i] == 'W' || text[i] == 'w')
      text_copy[i] = 'V';
    else
      text_copy[i] = toupper(text[i]);
  }

  return 'a';
}
```

It doesn't really matter what the function returns, however whenever I try to `printf("%s\n", text_copy);`, with some strings, it returns this:

```
belfast: BELFAST
please: PLEASE
aardvark: AARDVARK??
hello world: HELLO VORLD
taxxxiii: TAXXXIII???
swag: SVAG?
```

Why is it that some strings turn out fine and some don't? Thanks.

Comment: `text_copy` has local scope and it is not `null-terminated` and there isn't space for null-terminator.... .....

Comment: Do the question marks appear in the output or are they intended to mark the strings which are processed in a way other than expected?

Comment: @LPs setting `text_copy` to `textLength+1` and then `text_copy[textLength] = '\0';` seems to have taken care of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on where you are using `printf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to null-terminate the copy.

```
char text_copy[textLength+1];
...
text_copy[textLength]='\0';
```

Though if you are returning it from your function (that isn't clear) you should be mallocing it instead.

Comment: Worked, thanks. It isn't supposed to be returned from the function, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that some strings turn out fine and some don't?

Pure chance.

You only allocate enoufgh space for the visible characters in the string and not the terminating `\0`. You are just lucky that for some of the strings a null byte is on the stack just after the character array.

Change your code like so...

```
int textLength = strlen(text);
char text_copy[textLength + 1]; // << enough space for the strings and \0

for(int i = 0; i < textLength; i++){
  if(text[i] == 'W' || text[i] == 'w')
    text_copy[i] = 'V';
  else
    text_copy[i] = toupper(text[i]);
}
text_copy[textLength] = '\0'; // Make sure it is terminated properly.
```